# Field extension as vector spaces

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Let $F$ be a field and $K/F$ a field extension.
I have seen that we can consider the extension as a $F$ -vector space(scalars over $F$) Is this a kind of convention?
If not ,is there a proof about this?

Comment: Vector spaces have a lot of good properties and theorems, so if you can consider a thing as a vector space, it's a good idea to do that. And yes, any field extension can be viewed as a vector space. Prove it yourself, it's very easy.

Comment: How would it be convention? Either it is or is not a vector space. $K/F$ usually means $K\supset F$, thus $K$ is viewed as $F$-vector space. Scalar multiplication is just multiplication in the extension, you can verify the axioms yourself.

Comment: i see ,thank you ,i will do that!

Comment: I see your edit, but your terminology is still awkward. You wouldn't say that $\Bbb R^n$ is $\Bbb R^n$-vector space with scalars over $\Bbb R$, you would say that it is $\Bbb R$-vector space. Here, $K$ is $F$-vector space.

Comment: i edited,you are right

Comment: A field extension has even more than what vector space axioms require. For instance the existence of multiplication inverse for field elements and multiplication commutativity.

Comment: "How would it be convention?". Well, if someone says "Let $K$ be an extension of $F$, The __dimension__ $K$ is ....", then I'd say the use of the term "dimension" without explicitly noting that it is a vector space over $F$ amounts to a "convention".

Answer (score 0):

Let $$\star :K\times K\to K,(x,y)\mapsto x+y$$ where $+$ is the addition in $K$;

and$$\bullet :F\times K\to K, (k,x)\mapsto kx$$
where $kx$ is the result of the multiplication of $k$ and $x$ in $K(^1)$.

We can therefore use the usual notations for $\star$, the law of internal composition and $\bullet$, the law of external composition and verify for example that $(K,\star)$ is a commutative group as follows :

- $\forall x\in K, x+0=0+x=x$, where $0$ is the one of $K$;
- $\forall x,y \in K, x+(y+z)=(x+y)+z$, since it is true in $K$;
- $\forall x \in K, x+(-x)=(-x)+x=0$;
- $\forall x,y \in K, x+y=y+x$, since it is true in $K$.

(We could have gone faster by writing that $\star=+$ so that $(K,\star)$ is a commutative group since $(K,+) $ is)

The rest of the proof is just as easy...

And we can conclude
$$(K,\star,\bullet)\text{ is a vector space over }F.\square$$

---

$(^1)$Recall that saying that K is an *extension* of F means that F is a subfield of K. So $$k\in F\implies k\in K$$